# How multiply with 12 decimals in C?

Tags: c, double, precision, long-integer

I'm trying to have precision of 12 decimals in C. I don't know if there's an easier solution. But at least that code works. Now I'm just trying to save the result in a "long double" but "strtold()" is not working

```
char* multiply12Decimals(float n1, float n2)
{
    long n1Digits;
    sscanf(doubleToVoidPointerInNewMemoryLocation(n1*1000000), "%ld", &n1Digits);
    printf("n1Digits: %ld\n", n1Digits);

    long n2Digits;
    sscanf(doubleToVoidPointerInNewMemoryLocation(n2*1000000), "%ld", &n2Digits);
    printf("n2Digits: %ld\n", n2Digits);

    long long mult = (long long) n1Digits*n2Digits;
    printf("mult: %lld\n", mult);

    char *charNum = malloc(30*sizeof(char));

    sprintf (charNum, "0.%012lld\n", mult);
    printf("result: %s\n", charNum);

    return charNum;
}
```

Comment: There is no strtold in the code! What's the definition of "doubleToVoidPointerInNewMemoryLocation"

Comment: int main()
{
    float f1 = 2.053388;
    float f2 = 0.100269;

    long double f3;
    f3 = strtold(multiply12Decimals(f1,f2), NULL);
    printf("Final: %Lf", f3);

    return 0;
}

Comment: This code doesn't make sense at all. Why do you think you need to change stuff intermittently to strings and whatnot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%.12lf",num);` solves the problem.

Multiply two double and print it like this. No need to use `long`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that I was just complicating my life